# Typescript & React | Setting class property with an Enum is throwing error TS2349

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, typescript-class

I need some help on this one.

My goal is to create a **class C_GenericTask** for which I can change its properties. One of those properties is an **enum E_TaskState** with the following properties: TODO, DOING and DONE.

But when I try to use the setter of the C_GenericTask, typescript is throwing this error :

**TS2349: This expression is not callable. No constituent of type 'E_TaskState' is callable.**

I've done the typechecking and I don't see anything wrong.
Do you guys have an explanation ?
Here's my code :

C_GenericTask.ts

````
export default class C_GenericTask {
  protected _status: E_TaskState;

  constructor(title: string) {
    this._status = E_TaskState.TODO;
  }

  public get status(): E_TaskState {
    return this._status;
  }
  public set setStatus(value: E_TaskState) {
    this._status = value;
  }
}```



E_TaskState.ts

```enum E_TaskState {
  TODO,
  DOING,
  DONE,
}

export default E_TaskState;```



database.ts

```import C_GenericTask from "./classes/C_GenericTask";
import E_TaskState from "./Enum/E_TaskState";

let C_buildFirst = new C_GenericTask("Build First");

C_buildFirst.setStatus(E_TaskState.DONE);```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are using a setter here `public set setStatus(value: E_TaskState) {`

So you have two solutions:

```js
// Use the "classic" setter version (remove set)
public setStatus(value: E_TaskState) { ... }
// And then
genericTask.setStatus(...);


// Or use the setter version
public set status(value: E_TaskState) { ... }
// And then 
genericTask.status = ...;
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! 
I have one dumb question though. 

Why is not possible to use the set function as following : 
```public set status(value: E_TaskState) { ... }

// And then...

genericTask.status(..)```

Is it something specific to getters and setters ?
Because to me, it seems to be in total contradiction with the function writing standards.

Comment: It's a specific syntax indeed.